# MongoDB - very slow query execution when collation is set

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a problem with very slow query execution on the mongodb.
Generally I have persons collection and each person (about 40000000 records) has some documents (a few).
I would like to get documents for concrete person, sort them and finally get only one page of items.

The query look like:

```
db.getCollection('persons').aggregate([
{ "$match" : { "personIdCardNumber" : "XXXXX" } },
{ "$unwind" : "$documents" },
{ "$match" : { } },
{ "$sort" : { "documents.submitDate" : -1 } },
{ "$skip" : 0 },
{ "$limit" : 11 },
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "documents" : { "$push" : "$documents" } } }
],(
{ collation: { "locale" : "pl"}}))
```

When I will remove unwind, sort, group etc. the query also is very slow. When I remove collation the query becomes very fast (from 12s to ~50ms). When I set collation for "en" the query is a bit of faster but still is realy slow (~12s for "pl" vs ~8s for "en")

If someone has idea what can I do to have collation and provide better performance?

As for my c# code it is:

```
    collection.AggregateWithCollation()
        .Match(x => x.personIdCardNumber == idCardNumber)
        .Unwind(x => x.Documents)
        .Sort(sort)
        .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
        .Limit(pageSize + 1)
        .Group(group)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

no difference if i run the c# code or run the query directly on the database, the execution time is very similar.

Comment: Can this help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487947/mongodb-not-using-index-possible-collation-issue

Comment: db.getCollection('persons').aggregate([
{ "$match" : { "personIdCardNumber" : "xxx" } }
],(
{ collation: { "locale" : "pl", "strength" : 2, "numericOrdering" : "false"}}))


and 

db.getCollection('persons').find({personIdCardNumber: "XXXX"}).collation( { "locale" : "pl", "strength" : 2, "numericOrdering" : false})

Time: 30s vs 15s. Find is definitely faster but without collation, i have time less than 1s.


Maybe the issue is that the index (personIdCardNumber) has collection for English as default? So maybe the solution is re-create index with collation for PL?

Comment: I see that when i use collation the query uses collscan (check all 42kkk records), without collation, the query uses ixscan and use indexes.

Comment: Yes, you can try re-creating index and verify the explain plan

Comment: Create indexes with the collation you are using for queries.

Comment: Re-created indexes with collation works well. Thx.